# Add conditional statement in the static block in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, static-block, print

My following code is under static block and i am trying to achieve following functionality.

I print invoice using the following code:

```
{{if order_date == '03/06/2017'}}
    <td style='width: 15%;'>
        <span style='font-weight:bold; padding:5px; display:block; background:#e5e5e5;'>Tax(VAT/CST)</span>
    </td>
{{else}}
    <td style='width: 15%;'>
        <span style='font-weight:bold; padding:5px; display:block; background:#e5e5e5;'>Tax(GST)</span>
    </td>
{{/if}}
```

Update:-

My order date is `03/06/2017` and every time it is going into else statement and printing else statement instead of printing if statement.

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: @Marius i had updated the question with actual issue.

Answer (score 2):

Pradeep, I don't believe that the template filter system and the `{{if}}` directive supports operators (`==`). If you consult the class, `Varien_Filter_Template`, you would find that the `ifDirective` parser does not look for expression evaluation in the way you would expect.

Specifically, line `248` calls `$this->_getVariable`, which according to your directive is receiving `order_date = '03/06/2017'` as the `$value` argument, which cannot match any values stored in the filter processor.

The `_getVariable` method supports only a few types of values/operations:

- Direct variable name; eg: `order_data`
- `Varien_Object` instances; eg: `getOrderData()`
- Other objects with a corresponding method name; eg: `order_data()`

Another way to solve this problem is to supply a model/object in your conditional, like the order model, with a custom extending method, which you can call to to evaluate the expression outside of the filter processor, like this:

```
class Your_Module_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
    public function checkOrderDate($input)
    {
        return $this->getData('order_date') == $input;
    }
}
```

And then in your content, rewrite the directive like so:

```
{{if order.checkOrderDate('03/06/2017') }}
...
```

---

Here's a complete working test case:

```
require_once '/vagrant/public_html/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

class MockOrderClass extends Varien_Object
{
    public $order_date = '03/06/2017';

    public function checkOrderDate($input)
    {
        return $this->order_date == $input;
    }
}

$filter = new Varien_Filter_Template();
$filter->setVariables(array('order' => new MockOrderClass()));

$input = <<<EOF
{{if order.checkOrderDate('03/06/2017') }}
    <td style='width: 15%;'>
        <span style='font-weight:bold; padding:5px; display:block; background:#e5e5e5;'>Tax(VAT/CST)</span>
    </td>
{{else}}
    <td style='width: 15%;'>
        <span style='font-weight:bold; padding:5px; display:block; background:#e5e5e5;'>Tax(GST)</span>
    </td>
{{/if}}
EOF;

echo '<pre>' . (htmlentities($filter->filter($input))) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Actually i want to put condition like this {{if order.getShippingMethod(1).getMethod() == "pickupatstore_1"}}  <div class="name">
some text
</div>{{else}}
<div class="name">{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</div>
{{/if}}       but its not working in cms block magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont do your conditions with a pretty php tag in a **phtml** and the rendred will be displayed in your static block like this:

1) Create a phtml in :

```
app/design/frontend/{YourPackage}/{YourTheme}/template/cms/phtmlname.phtml
```

2) Put this piece of code in your static block:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="cms/phtmlname.phtml"}}
```