# how to get shipping methods in cms(in admin panel) but not programmatically using php magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, cms

> Actually i am trying to get selected shipping methods from checkout
>   page in cms(in admin panel). Here I want to put if else condition in
>   cms content only with selected shipping Method.

Actually i am trying this way because when we can get base url from cms also same way i am trying to get selected shipping Method

> {{store url="customer/account/"}}

Comment: Could you post the code script that you have implemented, so maybe someone can help you with? Also elaborate more on your question. :)

Comment: Please check this link worked for me.
[enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179454/add-conditional-statement-in-the-static-block-in-magento)

Comment: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179454/add-conditional-statement-in-the-static-block-in-magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179454/add-conditional-statement-in-the-static-block-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

i would implement it by creating a specific block for collecting and rendering available shipping methods and than place in in a cms page using:

```
{{block type="your/block" name="yourname"}}
```